# In Python how scrape page what content changes on each link?

Tags: python, web-scraping

In Python 3 I need to scrape a table on [this page](http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2010/14417/AC/10000000001/bens) or [this](http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2016/2/71072/250000004975/bens)

It is the table that has the columns "Descrição", "Tipo" and "Valor do Bem"

I did an inspect element and the table is:

```
<table class="table table-stripped dvg-table responsive">
```

But when showing the content of the requests, this item does not appear

It is a site with political profiles, so the header will be relatively fixed. The underside that will always change

Apparently the site link in the header is what the requests found. But the contents of the table are accessed differently. For each politician does the site look in another link to the table?

I did so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

requisicao = requests.get('http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2010/14417/AC/10000000001/bens')
# requisicao.content
sopa = BeautifulSoup(requisicao.content, "html.parser")
sopa.find("table", {"class": "table table-stripped dvg-table responsive"})
```

Please, does anyone know how I could access this table?

Comment: commenting to remind myself to answer later today when I'm back at my computer

Comment: @JohnH, for that purpose you can mark this question as "Favorite question" by clicking star  just below dovnvote arrow and it will be available on your personal page in  "favorites" tab. Click once more to remove question from favorites

Comment: @andersson thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get required data with below request:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/rest/v1/candidatura/buscar/2016/71072/2/candidato/250000004975"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.json())
```

More specific info you can get as

```
print(response.json()['bens'])
```

or

```
print(response.json()['partido'])
```

etc...

Comment: Thank you very much. Please, how did you get on this page? http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/rest/v1/candidatura/buscar/2016/71072/2/candidato/250000004975

Comment: Thank you. For example, in Firefox, when access "inspect element", should I use the Console menu? Which command shows the JSON page of the site?

Comment: You should use another tab. Neither "Inspector", nor "Console".. "Network" tab should be located between "Memory" and "Storage" tabs... I guess :)

Comment: Right. In the Network tab there are the GETs and beside menus (Headers, Cookies, Params ...). Sorry, I have not found the JSON site yet

Comment: Try to makeonly XHR tab enabled and try again - required GET request should be displayed there

Comment: Thank you. But the XHR tab is blank. Even pressing F5

Comment: Would you allow me to ask a new question about this? On the Stackoverflow. How to find JSON website with dev console

Comment: Yeh. It's better to ask another question. Maybe someone will help you...

Comment: Please, which browser and version did you use? And what operating system?

Comment: I don't think that it depends on browser or OS, but I use Firefox 58.0.1 and Windows 7