# How to check XHR that sends to get dynamic content in browser?

Tags: python, json, xmlhttprequest

I need to check which XmlHttpRequests sends to display dynamic data on [this site](http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2016/2/71072/250000004975/bens) do the scraping in Python

I've been informed that request to [this API source](http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/rest/v1/candidatura/buscar/2016/71072/2/candidato/250000004975) is send

In Firefox I do

- click on Inspect element on the first site above
- click on the Network tab.
- select XHR

But the JSON request did not appear. Nothing appears. Even pressing F5 or clearing the cache

Please, can it be some wrong configuration in my browser / dev console that does not allow displaying the XHR list? Or is there any way to do this?

Comment: did you go to the second link? its json...

Comment: Thank you. As I said above, what I need to know is how to discover this second site

Comment: What do you mean discover?

Comment: What is your question, and what have you tried?

Comment: This site (http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2016/2/71072/250000004975/bens) is publicly available. What I want to know is how to find the JSON version of it. I have several other sites to look for

Comment: I've already tried with the inspect element, the dev console. In Firefox

Comment: ok, i don't think its discoverable how you mean. what you probably need to do is slice up the json url you know, and start swapping out different sections. probably the id is one to start with.

Comment: Thank you. Earlier another colleague said it is possible (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649787/in-python-how-scrape-page-what-content-changes-on-each-link/48650212?noredirect=1#comment84302632_48650212 )

Comment: like notice how doria's id is in both urls? "250000004975", probably just need to write function swapping that stuff out.

Comment: He did it and told me how to do it, but it did not work out. So I asked another question to find more help.

Comment: what version of ff and os was he on? are you on?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04. Firefox Quantum

Comment: Reinaldo, the comments in that stack overflow question are talking about the firefox network monitor. From what I can tell from a brief google search, the network monitor will show you what requests are being made when you visit a part of the site. The url associated with the https request will indicate where to find the JSON associated with that particular web page.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to install this plugin

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves , you can also try sniffers like WireShark or Fiddler to monitor the requests you sent. But it's little more complicated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it; steps I took:
go to URL in firefox, click inspect, click network tab, refresh browser, click on xhr option in network tab.[image: Screenshot of finding JSON payload in Firefox network panel]

Comment: Thank you very much. Have you installed the firefox network monitor plugin? A colleague above indicated me

Comment: no i have not, that is firefox's default tooling you see in the screenshot

Comment: It’s not a plug-in. It’s a part of firefox. What albert did looks like the solution.